# How to find only English language words using Wiktionary search box?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wiktionary

How to find **only** english language words using Wiktionary's search box? I'm using [d*e](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=d%2Ae) as a query in the search box (words that begin with d letter and end at e letter).

By default Wiktionary's search box returns words also from non-english languages, words like **dainuojančiosiose** or **daiktavardžiuose**

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to filter the results using [`incategory`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Intitle_and_incategory) (and possibly `intitle`, if you want to be more specific). For example:

- [`intitle:d*e incategory:"English nouns"`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Search/intitle:d*e%20incategory:%22English%20nouns%22)
- [`intitle:d*e incategory:"English idioms"`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Search/intitle:d*e%20incategory:%22English%20idioms%22)

One problem with this approach is that you need to pick one of the many very specific ["English *" categories](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:PrefixIndex/Category:English) which exist on Wiktionary.